# Why does a Cisco router advertise a prefix with NDP RA when it has an address in that range?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, ipv6, ndp

If I write

```
interface Vlan1
 ... {ipv4 config} ...
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:5432:101::/64 eui-64
 ipv6 address FDAA:DB8:5432:101::/64 eui-64
 ipv6 enable
 ipv6 nd prefix 2001:DB8:5432:101::/64
 ipv6 nd prefix FDAA:DB8:5432:101::/64
 ipv6 nd other-config-flag
 ipv6 nd ra interval 4
 ipv6 dhcp server DHCP6_POOL
!
```

then the NDP RAs I see look like (tcpdump, machine connected to `Vlan1`)

```
IP6 (class 0xe0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 96) fe80::{router's eui-64} > ff02::1: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router advertisement, length 96
hop limit 64, Flags [other stateful], pref medium, router lifetime 1800s, reachable time 0ms, retrans timer 0ms
  source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): {router's eui-48}
  mtu option (5), length 8 (1):  1500
  prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): 2001:db8:5432:101::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 2592000s, pref. time 604800s
  prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): fdaa:db8:5432:101::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 2592000s, pref. time 604800s
```

exactly as expected. The prefixes being advertised are the ones configured with `ipv6 nd prefix *::/64`, no more, no fewer.

However, if I configure additional addresses on the interface with `ipv6 address` but don't add those prefixes as `ipv6 nd prefix` as follows

```
interface Vlan1
 ... {ipv4 config} ...
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:5432:101::/64 eui-64
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:5432:102::/64 eui-64
 ipv6 address FDAA:DB8:5432:101::/64 eui-64
 ipv6 address FDAA:DB8:5432:102::/64 eui-64
 ipv6 enable
 ipv6 nd prefix 2001:DB8:5432:101::/64
 ipv6 nd prefix FDAA:DB8:5432:101::/64
 ipv6 nd other-config-flag
 ipv6 nd ra interval 4
 ipv6 dhcp server DHCP6_POOL
!
```

then I would expect RAs for only the prefixes specified with `ipv6 nd prefix`, however I see RAs containing all four prefixes:

```
IP6 (class 0xe0, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 160) fe80::{router's eui-64} > ff02::1: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router advertisement, length 160
hop limit 64, Flags [other stateful], pref medium, router lifetime 1800s, reachable time 0ms, retrans timer 0ms
  source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): {router's eui-48}
  mtu option (5), length 8 (1):  1500
  prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): 2001:db8:5432:101::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 2592000s, pref. time 604800s
  prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): 2001:db8:5432:102::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 2592000s, pref. time 604800s
  prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): fdaa:db8:5432:101::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 2592000s, pref. time 604800s
  prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): fdaa:db8:5432:101::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 2592000s, pref. time 604800s
```

What configuration can I use to give the router all four addresses on `Vlan1`, but only advertise the original two - so that dynamic devices will only autoconfigure in 101 subnets, but the router can still also talk to servers statically assigned addresses within 102 subnets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ipv6 nd prefix default no-advertise
```

or list the interface addresses *not* to announce

```
ipv6 nd prefix 2001:DB8:5432:102::/64 no-advertise
ipv6 nd prefix FDAA:DB8:5432:102::/64 no-advertise
```

Comment: The former suppresses all prefixes in RAs and I don't see an option converse to `no-advertise`, so while I think `default no-advertise` + `prefix 2001:101 advertise` + `prefix 2001:102` would be neater, I'm happy with the working solution `prefix 2001:101` + `prefix 2001:102 no-advertise`. Thanks.

Comment: The former is how it's *supposed* to work. Looks like Cisco has yet another bug in their IPv6 thinking.